# Azure Data Factory - Group by ID and create a new column for every value

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a list with the column IDs (alphanumeric) and stock place.
The list has multiples rows with the same ID but different stock places.
I want to create a new column for every stock place.

Example:

```
id,stockplace
AB1, XA
AB1, XB
AB1, XC
AB2, YA
AB2, YB
```

The output shall be a new list:

```
id, stockplace1, stockplace2, stockplace3
AB1, XA, XB, XC
AB2, YA,YB
```

I first added a rowindexadder with value default 1. Then I sorted id and rowindex ascending.
Then I used the pivot feature like this:

1. GroupBy ID
2. PivotKey: Rowindex
3. PivotedColumn: Name pattern: Prefix{expression prefix}middle{pivot key value}suffix
   Arrangement: Normal

Expression:

What would be the expression?

Answer (score 0):

To get the output as your required format you can follow below procedure in data flow:

Setup the data source and add windows function transformation to create `row_index` column. Configure the transformation as follows:

- Over:`id`
- Sort: `id`
- Window columns:

  - `row_index : rowNumber()`

[image]

Add pivot transformation to the windows transformation and configure the transformation as follows:

- Group by: `id`
- Pivot key: `row_index`
- Pivoted columns :

  - `stocplace: max(stockplace)`

[image]

The new columns will create according to the data as mentioned below:

[image]