# Group IDs and concatenate their strings in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a CSV in Azure Data Factory (ADF) containing two columns ID & Text.
They look like this

```
ID,Text
A1, cheesecake
A1, buttercake
A2, apple
A2, banana
A2, melon
```

I want to merge them like this:

```
A1, cheesecake, buttercake
A2, apple, banana, melon
```

I used the aggregate feature and grouped first by ID. And then I tried to build an expression that concatenates all occurances of column "Text". But it never worked. When I use CHatGPT it doesn't bring the right answer. I recommends to use a function that is no longer supported in ADF.
Also in stack overflow I found two almost identical questions but they use expression methods that are no longer supported.
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below expression in the **aggregates**.

```
replace(replace(replace(toString(collect(Text)),'['),']'),'"')
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes I don't know how many occurences of a certain text are. There is a chance that for A2 I have 15 lines of "apple,banana etc.". Is your expression capped to only 3 text occurances?

Comment: No, it will work irrespective of number of occurances.

Comment: Thank you @Rakesh Govindula! I tried it and it works greatly :-)

Comment: One more question: I realized that having every occurance in one long concatenated string is not very advantagous. I would like to have dynamically new columns created for each occurance. So the end result would be A1, B1,B2,B3,B4,B5. And in each B-column I would have one occurance. I don't know in advance how many there will be. Is this possible?

Comment: I think you can try window transformation for that as mentioned in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76727846/azure-data-factory-group-by-id-and-create-a-new-column-for-every-value. If you face any issue raise a new ask with required details so that I can try if thats to my knowledge

Comment: You rock, thank you! Case closed.